# Entity framework Custom SQL and store result value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to run a simple custom SQL query, in my EF seeder, How can I implemented a simple SQL query and store the result (a count(), just an integer) in a c# variable?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "/*query*/";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param", paramValue));
var value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```